# C# Expandable Property

Tags: c#, syntax, properties, typeconverter

```
    public class ThemeProperty
    {
        public Color FColor { get; set; } = Color.White;
        public Color BColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public ThemeProperty Theme { get; set; } = new ThemeProperty();

    // Use. 
    public void Test()
    {
        Theme.BColor = Color.Gray;
        Theme.FColor = Color.Black;
        Theme = true; /*I wanted to make the feature active or passive, but
        I could not figure out how to define a property class for this line.*/
    }
```

Hi, I created an extensible property called Theme. Although I have two features in it, I want to use them if I am active or passive and I want to use them if I am active. I can create and control a feature in this, but it is not flexible. I want to define this feature as above, but I could not figure out how to do it. Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

I would like to add true-false values on the red line. Activating or deactivating a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can try somthing like this :

```
public class ThemeProperty
{
    public Color FColor { get; set; }
    public Color BColor { get; set; }
    public bool ActivePassive { get; set; }

    public void ThemeProperty(bool state)
    {
        ActivePassive = state;
        FColor = Color.White;
        BColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

and use the constructor to make is active passive via true/false. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried to explain in this way that I have not been flexible yet. Thank you for your reply, I will organize the question.

Answer (score 1):

Define one more property in your "ThemeProperty" class.

```
public class ThemeProperty
{        
    public Color FColor { get; set; } = Color.White;
    public Color BColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
}

// Use.
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public ThemeProperty Theme { get; set; } = new ThemeProperty();


public void Test()
{
     Theme.BColor = Color.Gray;
     Theme.FColor = Color.Black;
     Theme.Active = true;
}
```

Alternatively, if "Active" is required you may want to pass the Boolean for active to the constructor of the class. Also, as an observation, it is probably not a good practice to call a class "Property".  Any class that can be instantiated can be used as Type of a property. Below is an alternative to your initial version.

```
public class Theme
{        
    public Theme(bool active)
    {
        Active = active;
    }

    public Color FColor { get; set; } = Color.White;
    public Color BColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

// Use. 
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public Theme theme { get; set; }


public void Test()
{
    theme = new Theme(true) { BColor = Color.Gray, FColor = Color.Black };
}
```

Comment: I've tried to explain in this way that I have not been flexible yet. Thank you for your reply, I will organize the question.